# Confused by RVM's instructions for Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

Working to get RVM working with Capistrano and Rails 3.1rc5 and confused by the instructions I found.

RVM's website provides [these instructions](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/) that say:

> In the new option, you can do the following (adjust to your personal setup):

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path. 
require "rvm/capistrano"               # Load RVM's capistrano plugin. 
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ree@rails3'     # Or whatever env you want it to run in.
```

Now I assume they want this at the top of our `deploy.rb` file!?! I only ask because I've not seen a "`$:.`" in the, albeit few, `deploy.rb`'s that I've seen.

What does the line starting with "`$:.`" do exactly? And does it belong in `deploy.rb` or somewhere else?

Comment: and it seemed that after using the rvm-capistrano gem they created, it will advise you to remove that line: `RVM - Capistrano integration was extracted to a separate gem, install: 'gem install rvm-capistrano' and remove the '$LOAD_PATH.unshift' line`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$:` is a special Ruby variable that is equivalent to `$LOAD_PATH`, which is the path that Ruby searches whenever you use a `require` statement. Calling `.unshift(...)` on it adds the provided path to the **front** of the load path.

If you just called `require 'rvm/capistrano'` without the `$:.unshift` statement, you would get an error, because by default, RVM's Capistrano library is not in Ruby's load path. The reason you haven't seen this in other `deploy.rb` files is because typically, the only libraries that are needed are Capistrano's, which are already included by running `cap deploy` (or any of the other `cap` commands).

My `deploy.rb` files have this exact same code in them and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this needs to be at the top level, so that it gets set before any calls--i.e. before bundle, any rake tasks, etc. This has been problematic for me. In my case, my web and app servers are not the same, and I do not want rvm on the web server.

It also seems a little black magic, when the real solution is rather easy. After updating your code, set up a blessed gemset in an .rvmrc file, and nothing else needs to be done.

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:rvm:setup"

namespace :deploy do
  namespace :rvm do
    # Set up .rvmrc
    # Note, not using method described in:
    #   https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/
    # We want to use RVM only on the app server, so better to set up and bless an .rvmrc file
    task :setup, :roles => :app do
      run "cd #{latest_release}; rvm use 1.9.2@#{application} --rvmrc --create && rvm rvmrc trust"
    end
  end
end
```